# JQuery hover out two div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two HTML table row, When I hover first tr I want to show this and second tr and when mouse will be out of both tr second tr must be a hide.

How Can I do this using JQuery?

```
<tr class="pr_td_main pr1">
   <td>123</td>
   <td>15</td>
</tr>
<tr class="pr_td_desc pr1">
   <td colspan="3">description</td>
  <td colspan="2">123<br />456</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is very confusing. Do you want the _desc to show when you mouse over the _main?

If that's the case you can do:

```
$(".pr_td_main").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).next(".pr_td_desc").show();
});
```

And to hide it when user moves his mouse out:

```
    $(".pr_td_desc").mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).hide(); //hide this tr

     });
```